how do i unistall ubuntu and reinstall windows 11
I have a lenovo ideapad flex 5. I installed ubuntu and because of compatibility reasons I
would like to reinstall windows. How do I do this and what usb flashers can i use?

You don't remove an unwanted OS; you just install the new OS over it.  Download and install as per instructions on Microsoft's website.
